# Singularity and laurent series for sinus function

Tags: laurent-series, trigonometric-series, singularity

I'm trying to find which kind of singularity this function has;

$$f(z) = \sin\left(\frac 1 {z-1}\right)$$

by using Laurent Series in a circle-area around $z=1$. Now usually the question is focused around $z=0$, so that I can use maclaurin series for the sinus function, but in this case I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: If you plug $\frac{1}{z-1}$ into the MacLaurin series of $\sin w$, what do you get?

Comment: I can't use the MacLaurin series, since I'm at a circle-area around z=1. As far as I know, I can only use MacLaurin if I'm in a circle-area around z=0.

Comment: @armara, you can use the taylor expansion of $\sin$ in the point $z=1$. (notice that MacLaurin is the taylor expansion of $\sin$ in the point $z=0$).

Comment: @armara I think Daniel means that if $\sin w = \sum a_nw^n$, then you can write $\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)=\sum a_n(z-1)^{-n}$